# How to convert a csv file to one with unicode utf-8 encoding and maintain french accents?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

Usually, french accents can be displayed using utf-8. Unfortunately, I have a csv file where this is not the case, but I need it to be encoded in utf-8 and the accents to be visible. How can I do this?

p.s.: When it comes to programming, I know some basic python.

Comment: First you need to figure out what encoding the existing file uses, if it isn't UTF-8.

Comment: *"Usually, french accents can be displayed using utf-8."* - Not usually, *always*.

Comment: ...you need to show input data, describe what you expect to see, describe what you see instead, tell what tools you're using (text editors? command line? Python version? Windows? Linux?) and show any code you have tried so far.

Comment: @Tomalak if they were using Linux I'd expect utf-8 to work.  Windows is the brain-dead OS that favors backward compatibility over working properly on modern text.

Comment: @MarkRansom There's no telling without seeing more details in the question. There could be all kinds of things wrong, even on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer** 
Save the file as a CSV from Excel without utf-8 encoding. Reopen the CSV file with notepad and then save as a CSV file with utf-8.

**References and Additional Links** 
https://support.waysact.com/hc/en-us/articles/203979700-CSV-Excel-Saving-Accented-Characters

Comment: Where did the OP say that they are using Excel?

Comment: I was assuming they were, my bad. If they are not using excel the second part of my solution still applies.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: No Problem. If you don't mind, please mark this as the accepted answer, I am trying to increase my reputation. Thanks!